# Maximum GCD of partitions of a number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across a interesting theorem that, if we have a number n and we want to divide it into k parts such that sum of all k parts is equal to n, then the highest possible GCD of those partitions is equal to n/sum, where sum is the sum of 1+2+...k. I need the proof of this theorem and intuition behind it.

Comment: for eg. let n=216 and we want to divide it in 3 partitions then we can calculate the maximum GCD possible by n/(1+2+3) = 216/6 = 36. The partitions are 36 , 72 and 108

Comment: Welcome to the site. Pl present your question in Mathjax and follow the instructions on the tourguide of the page.

Comment: I've edited the question for you this time. Also please note the source of your theorem

Comment: For starters, the gcd of the partition numbers must divide $n$ as well. Hence the gcd must be less than or equal to $n$

Comment: One more thing is that, this clearly shows that for the maximum number of partitions i.e: when we have $n$ pieces of $n$ the gcd drops down to one

Comment: Take e.g. $n = 12 = 6 + 6$, so $k = 2$ parts. Then $\gcd(6, 6) = 6$ but $12 / (1 + 2) = 4$?

Comment: Maybe you need each partition number to distinct? @prets

Comment: @KartikaySharma I give you a hint by the example you gave. If parts could be the equal, then $216$ could be split into 3 parts evenly, as $$216=72+72+72$$ but if you want the parts to be all different, then they must be of the form $$a_1 d + a_2d + a_3d=n$$ with $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$. You get the largest gcd minimizing the sum of $a_1+a_2+a_3$, simply picking $1,2,3$.

Comment: @Crostul Yeah! I got it. Thanks, for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

Following Crostul's hint:

Suppose $d$ is the GCD of each element in the set $\{p_1,p_2..,p_k\}$ then, dividing each element by it, we get $\{a_1,a_2.,a_3..,a_k\}$. Allowing us to write:

$$ d(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i) = n$$

Or,

$$ d = \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^k a_i}$$

Of course since the elements are distinct, we can assume wlog that $a_i< a_{i+1}$, in the natural numbers (no 0), we can make the sum the least by replacing the elements by the least elements in the $\mathbb{N}$ while satisfying constraint.

From the above, we get the inequality:

$$ 1+2..+k \leq \sum_{i=1}^k a_i$$

Plugging this into the expression for $d$ isolated on LHS gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

This theorem is not true.

As a counter-example, look at the case where $n = \alpha k$ (for $k > 1$).
Here, by setting the partitions all to equal size $\alpha$ we can get the GCD to be $\alpha = \frac{n}{k} > \frac{n}{1 + \cdots + k} $.

For the rest of this answer, I will assume that the theorem states that the partitions had to be ***distinct***.

To prove this we start by naming $G(n, k)$ to be the largest such gcd you can find when splitting $n$ into $k$ distinct parts.

Now, we assume that $G(n,k) > \frac{n}{1+\cdots + k}$ (setting up a proof by contradiction).

Next then notice that the partitions are therefore of the form,
$$G(n, k) \alpha_1,G(n, k) \alpha_2, \ldots,G(n, k)\alpha_k$$
where $\alpha_i$ is a positive integer.

Now we since we know this is equal to $n$ we have

$$n = G(n,k) \left(\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_k\right)$$

Now we pick the best possible case for our $\alpha_i$, clearly $gcd(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k) = 1$ otherwise, $G(n, k)$ would not be the largest possible. And finally, by selecting the smallest possible $\alpha_i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$.

We get that in the best case, $n = G(n, k)\left(1 + 2 + \cdots + k\right)$

$$\Rightarrow G(n,k) \not{>} \frac{n}{1 + 2 + \cdots + k}$$

$$\Rightarrow G(n,k) \leq \frac{n}{1 + 2 + \cdots + k}$$

Comment: The problem statement might have changed, but currently it states that the partitions have to be distinct :)